# Slow Performance for filtering markers in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I need an advice for the react-leaftlet port of leaflet. I am generating markers on a map and use marker clustering with react-leaflet-markercluster. Each markerdata is associated with some data. I want to filter that data based on the markers in the viewport.

My idea: Get the boundaries of the map and cross-check with each markers. Yes, it works. But the **performance is extremly slow** (> 4.5secs for calculating), when adding more than 500 markers.

What can I do to increase the performance?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CustomMarkers from './components/CustomMarkers';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import ImageContainer from './components/ImageContainer';
import { checkIfMarkerOnMap, createSampleData } from './utils/helpers';
import L from 'leaflet';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '400px',
        latitude: 40.00,
        longitude: 20.00,
        zoom: 5
      },
      visibleMarkers: {},
      markers : {},
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const sampleData = createSampleData(1000);
    this.setState({ markers: sampleData, visibleMarkers: sampleData });
    const mapBoundaries = this.mapRef.contextValue.map.getBounds();
    this.setState({ mapBoundaries });
  }

  getMapBoundaries = () => {
    // Get map boundaries
    const mapBoundaries = this.mapRef.contextValue.map.getBounds();
    if(this.state.mapBoundaries !== mapBoundaries){
      console.log("different");
      this.setState({ mapBoundaries } );
    } else return;
  }

  checkVisibleMarkers = () => {
    console.time("checkVisibleMarkers");
    const { markers, mapBoundaries } = this.state;
    let visibleMarkers = Object.keys(markers)
      .filter(key => (L.latLngBounds([[mapBoundaries._southWest.lat, mapBoundaries._southWest.lng], [mapBoundaries._northEast.lat, mapBoundaries._northEast.lng]]).contains([markers[key].coordinates.latitude,markers[key].coordinates.longitude])))
      .map(key => { return { [key] : markers[key] } });
    visibleMarkers = Object.assign({}, ...visibleMarkers);
    console.log("visibleMarkers", visibleMarkers);
    // this.setState({ visibleMarkers })
    console.timeEnd("checkVisibleMarkers");
  }

  handleViewportChanged = () => {
    this.getMapBoundaries();
    this.checkVisibleMarkers();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.mapRef", this.mapRef);
    const { viewport, markers, visibleMarkers } = this.state;
    const position = [viewport.latitude, viewport.longitude]
     return (
       <Fragment> 
        <Map 
          ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref }} 
          center={position} 
          zoom={viewport.zoom}
          maxZoom={15}
          onViewportChanged={() => this.handleViewportChanged()} 
          style={{ height: '400px' }}>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          />
            <CustomMarkers visibleMarkers={markers} />
        </Map>
        {/* <ImageContainer visibleMarkers={visibleMarkers} /> */}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

CustomMarker.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Marker, Tooltip } from 'react-leaflet';
import uuid from 'uuid-v4';
import { 
    heartIcon, 
    heartIconYellow, 
    heartIconLightblue, 
    heartIconDarkblue } from './../icons/icons';
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';
import L from 'leaflet';


class CustomMarkers extends Component {
    render() {
        const { visibleMarkers } = this.props;
        let markers; 
        if(Object.keys(visibleMarkers).length > 0) {
            markers = Object.keys(visibleMarkers).map(key => {
                let latitude = visibleMarkers[key].coordinates.latitude;
                let longitude = visibleMarkers[key].coordinates.longitude;
                let icon = heartIcon;
                if(visibleMarkers[key].category === 'fb') icon = heartIconLightblue;
                if(visibleMarkers[key].category === 'blogs') icon = heartIconYellow;
                if(visibleMarkers[key].category === 'artisan') icon = heartIcon;
                if(visibleMarkers[key].category === 'website') icon = heartIconDarkblue;
                return (
                    <Marker 
                        key={uuid()}
                        position={ [latitude, longitude] } 
                        icon={icon}    
                    >
                        <Tooltip>{visibleMarkers[key].category}</Tooltip>
                    </Marker>
                    )
            }); 
        }

        const createClusterCustomIcon = (cluster) => {
            return L.divIcon({
              html: `<span>${cluster.getChildCount()}</span>`,
              className: 'marker-cluster-custom',
              iconSize: L.point(40, 40, true),
            });
          }
        return (
            <MarkerClusterGroup 
                iconCreateFunction={createClusterCustomIcon}
                disableClusteringAtZoom={10} 
                zoomToBoundsOnClick={true}
                spiderfyOnMaxZoom={false} 
                removeOutsideVisibleBounds={true}
                maxClusterRadius={150}
                showCoverageOnHover={false}
                >
                    {markers}
            </MarkerClusterGroup>      
        )
    }
}
export default CustomMarkers;
```

createSampleData takes the amount of sample data to generate as an input and creates a json structure for sample data { id: 1 { coordinates: {},...}

The **bottleneck** is the function **checkVisibleMarkers**. This function calculates if the marker is in viewport. **Mathimatically its just two multiplications per marker.**

Comment: Have you been able to identify which part of the code is the bottleneck? For example, is it the `checkVisibleMarkers` function?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody, yes, exactly. checkVisibleMarkers is the bottleneck. This function calculates if the marker is in viewport. Mathimatically its just two multiplications per marker.

Comment: Can you setup and share a codepen to work on?

Comment: @Mario it looks like you're creating a new UID (using `uuid()`) on each rerender of the map. This could mean every marker is being rerendered, which is probably causing some of the performance issues you're seeing. I've updated my solution to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few potential issues - the performance of the `checkVisibleMarkers` function, ***and*** the use of `uuid()` to create unique (and different) `key` values on each rerender of a `<Marker />`.

#### `checkVisibleMarkers`

Regarding the `checkVisibleMarkers` function. There's a few calls and patterns in there which could be optimized. Here's what's currently happening:

1. Create an array of the markers keys
2. Loop through the keys, reference the corresponding marker and filter by location using `L.latLngBounds().contains()`
3. Loop through the filtered keys to create an array of objects as `{key: marker}`
4. Use `Object.assign()` to create an object from the array of objects

In the end, we have an object with each value being a marker.

I'm unsure of the internals of `L.latLngBounds` but it could be partly responsible for the bottleneck. Ignoring that, I'll focus on refactoring the `Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys().filter().map())` pattern using a `for...in` statement.

```
checkVisibleMarkers = () => {
  const visibleMarkers = {};
  const { markers, mapBoundaries } = this.state;

  for (let key in markers) {
    const marker = markers[key];
    const { latitude, longitude } = marker.coordinates;

    const isVisible = mapBoundaries.contains([latitude, longitude]);

    if (isVisible) {
      visibleMarkers[key] = marker;
    }
  }

  this.setState({ visibleMarkers });
}
```

A quick check on jsPerf shows the above method is ~50% faster than the method you're using, but it doesn't contain the `L.latLngBounds().contains()` call so it's not an exact comparison.

I also tried a method using `Object.entries(markers).forEach()`, which was slightly slower than the `for...in` method above.

#### The `key` prop of `<Marker />`

In the `<Marker />` component you're using `uuid()` to generate unique keys. While unique, each rerender is generating a new key, and every time a component's key changes, React will create a new component instance. This means every `<Marker />` is being recreated on every rerender.

The solution is to use a unique, and permanent, key for each `<Marker />`. Thankfully it sounds like you already have a value that will work for this, the `key` of `visibleMarkers`. So use this instead:

```
<Marker 
  key={key}
  position={ [latitude, longitude] } 
  icon={icon}    
>
  <Tooltip>{visibleMarkers[key].category}</Tooltip>
</Marker>
```

Comment: thanks @brett, really good idea performance wise to do a for-in-loop instead of map filter.  If I have a 1000 markers on the map it's working. If I increase to 5k it's for sure better, still low performance.

Comment: Hmmm, there seems to be biggest pain in performance, when i am setting the visibleMarkers in the state. If I remove the setstate method it works great.

Comment: Are you able to test the `L.latLngBounds().contain()` method to see if that's the culprit. For example, replacing that conditional with a simple function. You might also be able to create a reference to `L.latLngBounds()` so it's not calculated on every iteration. Like `const bounds =  L.latLngBounds([[sW.lat, sW.lng], [nE.lat, nE.lng]]);`, then `const isVisible = bounds.contains([latitude, longitude])`.

Comment: This was one issue. thank you. The const mapboundaries is alreadyd the result of L.latLngBounds() so "let isVisible = mapBoundaries.contains([latitude, longitude]);", increase the speed

Comment: I think I was wrong with the bottleneck. With the callback onViewportChanged I am triggering this state update and I guess, it's called multiple times. update follows. thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like there are multiple bottlenecks, but glad you're moving in the right direction.

Comment: FWIW if you have a LOT of points you might also want to look into whether it would make sense for you to use something like an RTree to store your points. RTrees are reeeeally fast at answering queries like "Give me all the points that exist within this rectangle".

Comment: @BrettDeWoody, thanks for the hints in the right direction. I managed it, the issue was something different. With triggering a new state in the map component, when visibleMarkers update the state. The map component gets rerendered and rerendered and .....  n-times (n = visibleMarkers.length). So yeah. I guess a conceptual issue. What  would be the right way to post the solution? Update my question or post an answer and check it?

Comment: Interesting, you can post an answer to your own question and accept it.